# Dart http package for https communication - AppStore Export compliance

Tags: flutter, dart, app-store, app-store-connect

I am using [HTTP](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package from Dart in my Flutter-based mobile app. The HTTP package is used for https communication between server and client.

While I was preparing the submission of new version of the app in App Store, it seems there is a requirement to submit documentation if the app is using standard encryption algorithms but with non Apple API's e.g. `URLSession`.

So my question is, anyone knows if the HTTP package of Dart uses `URLSession` internally or does it have its own implementation of https along with all the encryption? and do I need to provide an Export Compliance doc for using that package?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the http package source code, it seems this package relies only on the Dart SDK.

There is a [CUPHTTPClientDelegate.m](https://github.com/dart-lang/http/blob/master/pkgs/cupertino_http/src/CUPHTTPClientDelegate.m) sub-package in it that's marked as experimental, where they say:

> Using the Foundation URL Loading System, rather than the [socket-based dart:io HttpClient](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/HttpClient-class.html) implemententation, has several advantages...

Therefore, I would think it's safe to assume that the package does not currently use `UrlSession`.

`dart:io.HttpClient` uses this [SecurityContext](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/5b8936496673a285bf8f37472119bc2afb38a295/sdk/lib/io/security_context.dart#L20) code to do TLS. Parts of it are implemented in the native code of the Dart SDK.

It seems that `dart-lang/sdk/runtime/bin/security_context.cc` is where crypto is implemented, and that uses `openssl` includes:

```
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/pkcs12.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>
```

So, that's what actually implements all crypto in the Dart SDK, it seems. I think Apple will be alright with that given there are lots and lots of Flutter Apps in the Apple Store and most of them are definitely using Dart's TLS.

> do I need to provide an Export Compliance doc for using that package?

I am no lawyer so I cannot give legal advice, but my understanding is that for "mass market cryptography" (which OpenSSL may be classified as) you do not need to worry about Export Compliance. Maybe have a look at [Mass Market](https://www.bis.doc.gov/index.php/policy-guidance/encryption/3-license-exception-enc-and-mass-market/a-mass-market) for more accurate information.